# Excel VBA - cells() parameters: Is there any difference in efficiency between passing in an integer or string?

Tags: excel, vba

If you've ever worked with cells in Excel VBA you've probably passed in integer values like this:

```
Cells(2, 3)
```

Which is a reference to cell C2. What many people don't know is that you can optionally pass in a string for the second parameter/argument, like this:

```
Cells(2, "C")
```

My question is: is there any difference in efficiency? I didn't find anything in the Microsoft documentation about this, but I'm guessing that the string is converted to an integer or long at run time, which would mean that there is a slight difference in performance (faster to pass in an integer).

Comment: This is easy to test?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't ask Google the right question?  Snide comment aside; I will say, "Yes, there is a difference and the integer will be faster".  I will also qualify that by saying, "Based on the results and explanations of testing done by other people".  It's faster for the same reason that `If Len(SomeString)=0` is faster than  `If SomeString = vbNullString` and why `If SomeString = ""` is the slowest of the three.  It's all numbers under the hood and string conversion is comparatively very, very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy to test indeed, Tim.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim value
    Dim n As Long, t As Double

    Debug.Print "Number of Iterations: "; FormatNumber(Rows.Count, 0)
    Debug.Print "Cells(n, 3)",
    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To Rows.Count
        value = Cells(n, 3)
    Next
    Debug.Print "Time in Seconds: "; Round(Timer - t, 4)

    Debug.Print "Cells(n, ""C"")",
    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To Rows.Count
        value = Cells(n, "C")
    Next
    Debug.Print "Time in Seconds: "; Round(Timer - t, 4)
End Sub
```

[image: Immediate Window Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks TinMan! This seems to confirm my suspicion. It looks like there is a significant difference for larger data sets or big loops, but negligible performance difference for short loops or small data sets.